# Using new smart pointers in std collections

Tags: c++11, clang, smart-pointers

Example, I have a CarPool class that creates lots of Car objects. It stores them in a `vector<Car*> all_cars_;`

The `Car` class is actually a base type of many different types of cars (so a `vector<Car>` would not work as I understand it).

I have some `Person` objects that may have access to some of these cars. The `Person` class stores them in a `vector<Car*> my_cars_;`.

The CarPool object will always outlive the Person objects and so is responsible for the ownership. Because of this I was thinking about making the CarPool collection into `vector<unique_ptr<Car>> all_cars_;`

Should I update the `Person` classes at all? If so, what should the `all_cars_` collection hold? Or should they remain as old-school pointers? Are old-school pointers still a 'modern' way of referring to objects?

Comment: Hmm, I'd prefer just `vector<Car>` if possible.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes I agree, but I expect Car might be a base class for various different derived types of cars in which case accessing them via a pointer is necessary to avoid slicing.

Comment: @R. Actually it is a base type. However, if it wasn't and I did do a Vector<car> in the CarPool class, what would you have in the Person class?

Comment: Can you please add that, and any other relevant information, to the question? (i.e. there are too many scenarios to consider here; this works better if you narrow the options down a little)

Comment: "The CarPool object will always outlive the Person objects" — your objects live in a *dreadful* world...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<unique_ptr<Car>> all_cars_;
```

sounds ideal for your application.  Whoever owns `all_cars`, then also owns all of the `Car*`s in `all_cars`.  And this will be superior to:

```
vector<Car*> all_cars_;
```

for at least 2 reasons:

1. you won't have to worry about the memory ownership code any longer.
2. The compiler will keep you from accidentally having more than one entity own any of the pointers in `all_cars_`.

For:

```
vector<Car*> my_cars_;
```

it sounds like these are *non-owning* pointers.  And so keeping them as `Car*` is perfectly reasonable.  This also allows you to freely make copies of any of these pointers.  The only thing you'll need to watch out for is the invalidation of the pointers due to changes in `all_cars_`, which you are surely already managing with your current design.